# Export html from draft js editor and keeping the style

Tags: html, reactjs, draftjs

I am using draft js to create email templates in a reactJs application.
I implemented custom block types and with css I was able to align my columns properly (left, center, right). I used `RichUtils` to toggle block type.

However, my problem is when I am exporting the editor state into html, only the tags are exported, but I need the style too, so that the `text-align` style remains the same.

I use `stateToHtml` from `draft-js-export-html` when exporting the html.
I was also thinking about adding custom attributes, but I was not successful with it yet.

I appreciate every answer and thank you for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this way:

```
import { ContentState, convertToRaw } from 'draft-js';
import draftToHtml from 'draftjs-to-html';

const currentContent = this.state.editorState.getCurrentContent();
return draftToHtml(convertToRaw(currentContent));
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it returns an empty string

Comment: So hard to navigate. I think it will be better if you lay out the code

Comment: @ArtemZubarev has provided a proper solution. It should work

Answer (score 0):

As an extension on **@ArtemZubarev** , there will be a problem when exporting it to html because it will contain no styles. So this requires 2 answers

**How to get state to html**: `credits to @ArtemZubarev`

```
import { ContentState, convertToRaw } from 'draft-js';
import draftToHtml from 'draftjs-to-html';

const currentContent = this.state.editorState.getCurrentContent();
return draftToHtml(convertToRaw(currentContent));
```

However, this will return unstyled elements, for example: `<h1>Hello World</h1>`.
This raises the question: **How to keep the styling?**

**Option 1**: CSS
**Option 2**: Create a render function that will inject the styles as inline

```
private injectHTML = (html?: string) => {
    return `<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    body {background-color: powderblue;}
    h1   {color: blue;}
    p    {color: red;}
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    ${
      html
    }
    
    </body>
    </html>`
  }
```